# SP 2010 CSOM Javascript: Intermittent Failure

Tags: 2010, javascript, access-denied, csom, jsom

I have inherited some JS code that is playing up.  It looks something like this:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MyFunc, "sp.js")
function MyFunc() {
  var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(servRelativeUrl);
  var web = ctx.get_web();
  var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTItle);
  ctx.load;
  ctx.load(list, "EffectiveBasePermissions");
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(successFunc, failFunc);
}
```

The problem I am having, is that this code only works sometimes.  If you have not been to the page for a few minutes, the code will almost always fail with `UnauthorizedAccessException: You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.` from the async call.  If you have been to the page recently, the code works.

I can reproduce the error on two farms using the same code.

Edit: I have checked the logs on the WFEs.  I can see the request happen.  with an error message `Unknown SPRequest error occured. More information 0x80070005 <GUID>`

Comment: The `ClientContext` has a timeout feature, which is causing your problem. Unfortunately, I've never found a way to modify the timeout settings via code, it must be set globally on the server.

Comment: Awesome! Any hints on the best steps to verify this is the problem?

Comment: Not at the moment. Maybe tomorrow when I get to work. _All I know is_, I wrote an extensive JavaScript library incorporating `ClientContext`. Due to this issue, I ripped it apart, replacing with REST and WebServices.

Comment: Here's the reference for `"sp.js"`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557057%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've had this error too!

The way I fixed it was described on a blog by Wictor Wilén. The way he explains it is that there is a token on the SharePoint page that has a timeout. If the token has expired then you can no longer make valid calls.

Luckily you can refresh the token at any time

```
UpdateFormDigest(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl, _spFormDigestRefreshInterval);
```

- This is a synchronous call, so no callbacks required
- It only updates the token if required, so it is quite fast if your token hasn't expired

**Blog:** http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-how-to-refresh-the-request-digest-value-in-javascript

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work :(

Comment: @Alex sorry I just noticed you're using 2010. This solution might only apply for 2013

Comment: @jasonscript - this solution is not working for me either. however i am using SharePoint 2013. Do you know any other way around ? Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Sorry @RohitWaghela I don't have any other work-around. Did you try reading Wictor's blog - linked in answer? He provides a lot more information than I do here

Comment: Thanks @jasonscript. Wictor's blog helped me out to resolving this issue. My code is working fine, when refreshing the token as suggested in this blog.